# Spin an object around a rotating axis?

Tags: animation

I want to spin my propeller blade along its axis, but this axis needs to rotate as part of the aircraft.
[image]

As you can see, the ducted fans rotate about a central axis and i want the propellers inside of them to rotate as well while spinning, but have no idea how to animate this

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Parent propeller to the "stick" and parent the ducts to an empty put where the dot is. Rotate propeller locally and ducts globally (x axis). Done.

Comment: @Alex Band: Yes, it would. Parented objects can be transformed freely.

Comment: Im trying to get it to rotate about the local axis but am struggling to get it to do so, an advice?

Comment: Hit **R** once and then the axis key **twice**.

Comment: when i do that, it seems to rotate about the z and x axis at the same time, creating this weird wobbling effect. is it possible to have 2 separate motions running at the same time?